# Read shapefiles in Python and render on Google Maps?

Tags: python, shapefile, google-maps

Is possible to read shapefiles in Python and render them on Google Maps? After research I'm really confused. Should I convert shapefiles to KML?

Comment: Google Maps will display KML natively. This your easiest route.